# Non-normalized colour-conversion Yxy colour space

Tags: colors, converters, color-space, cielab

I'm doing a psychology experiment involving colour.

Before I start my analysis I have to convert three colours in Yxy colour space into CIELAB. I used a colour spectrometer gun, but my luminances in Yxy space are non-normalized (in 1000s, up to infinity.) I need to get them to be either normalized luminances between 1-100 so I can use the converters I have found.

If anyone can help me with either normalizing my L values, or fully converting my Yxy values into CIELAB that'd be great!

My means in (Y, x, y) are:

`Peach: (1218.333, 0.362, 0.341)`

`Yellow: (2105, 0.393, 0.424)`

`Grue: (340.333, 0.262, 0.357)`